# Why onCompleted is not called in this code?

Tags: rx-java

I have this subject in the viewmodel:

```
private PublishSubject<String> articleSubject;

public Observable<Article> newArticleSubject() {
    articleSubject = PublishSubject.create();
    return articleSubject.flatMap(new Func1<String, Observable<Article>>() {         
        @Override
        public Observable<Article> call(String articleId) {
            return dataModel.getArticleById(articleId).subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread());
        }
    });
}
```

I bind the view like this:

```
viewModel.newArticleSubject()
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe(new ArticleSubscriber());
```

And this is my subscriber:

```
 private class ArticleSubscriber extends Subscriber<Article> {

        @Override
        public void onCompleted() {
            Log.d("test", "This is not ever printed");
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable e) {
            //do stuff
        }

        @Override
        public void onNext(Article article) {
            //do stuff
        }
}
```

`onCompleted` is never called, but `onError` and `onNext` are. Why? Inside `dataModel.getArticleById(articleId)`, `subscriber.onCompleted();` is called.

Comment: If `onError` is called, `onComplete` will *not* be called; that's by design.

Comment: I mean, in case that it fails, onError is called. But when everything is ok, onCompleted isn't

Comment: As it's a `PublishSubject`, someone is not calling onComplete on the `articleSubject`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As one can conclude from the image available in [`PublishSubject` the documentation](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/subjects/PublishSubject.html):

[image]

`PublishSubject` as well as other `*Subjects` will *live* until somone calls `onError` or `onCompleted`. In fact they **are no different in this matter** from any other [`Observable`](http://reactivex.io/documentation/observable.html).

The `newArticleSubject` creates new `PublishSubject` and *flat maps* every item emitted to a different observable. In case `getArticleById` ends with error the observable returned by `flatMap` ends too. However when `getArticleById` emits and completes normally `flatMap` will continue to *wait* for new items to be emitted by `articleSubject`. If you need to explicitely end `articleSubject` just call `articleSubject.onCompleted()`

Comment: Thank you very much. I understand now :)